# Is there a prevalent notation for the set $\{-n+1, …, n-1\}$?

Tags: notation

Quite often, the set $\{0, …, n-1\}$ is denoted by $[n]$. Is there similarly a notion for the set $\{-n+1,…,n-1\}$ (other and shorter than $[n] ∪ -[n]$)?

Comment: Of course, you can always invent your own notation. Why not just $\mathscr Z_n$ or some such?

Comment: I ever saw $[n]:=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ instead of your version starting with zero. The point is that the set $[n]$ had $n$ points, that is, a index set to count $n$ objects.

Answer (score 3):

Knowing I work only with integers, I like the open interval notation $(-n, n)$ or the french open interval notation $]-n, n[$.  If context is unclear you can write $(-n, n) \cap \mathbb Z$.

Note that $[n]$ can be written $[0, n)$ in interval notation.